# Android: Override a method in higher API level

Tags: java, android, overriding

How can I override a method which is present only in a higher API level than my minimum level?

Specifically I want to override a class which extends *View* class and I need to override *setBackground()* method.

- but when I **use** *"@Override"* Annotation I get the error:

"error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

- and when I **don't use** the *"@Override"* Annotation I get the error:

"This method is not overriding anything with the current build target, but will in API level 16 (current target is 10)"

Comment: have you tried using @TargetApi (16) ?

Comment: @panini, I did try @TaretAPI(16) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your build target to 16 or higher. In Eclipse, this is in Project > Properties > Android. In Android Studio, this is the `compileSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` file.

Then, add the `@Override` annotation.

The method won't be called on earlier versions of Android (unless you try calling it yourself, in which case your implementation will need to address that, perhaps with an `IllegalStateException` or something). But it will override the proper method on API Level 16+.